# Nested Models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have two models, Student and School

```
#in student.rb
has_one :school, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :school

#in school.rb
belongs_to :student
validates_presence_of :name
```

Now I have a script that uploads the names of the students from an excel file. But after uploading the names, I would like to build the school attributes during editing the student model.

```
#in my students controller,
def edit
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  if !@student.school
    @student.build_school
  end
end

#and in my edit view,
<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>
      .
      .
  <%= f.fields_for :school, :wrapper => false do |user| %>
     .
     .
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But the problem is the school model is not being built, hence not displayed. Thanks

Comment: `@student.build_school` should be done in `new` method and define your `strong parameters`

Comment: I have defined the strong params, did not show it up there. My problem is I am creating the students from another script. Students are created without the schools.

Comment: so you are saying there is no reference id or reference school record in the school table for a particular user when a user is created by script

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
def new
 @student   = Student.new
 @school = @student.school   
 @student.build_school     
end

def edit
 @student = Student.find(params[:id])
 @school = @student.school  unless @student.school
end
```

Hope that helps